# Why was Max Verstappen not required to start on his Q2 tyres in the Hungary GP?

Tags: formula-1

[This article (in Dutch)](https://www.nu.nl/nu-formule-1/6215274/verstappen-nam-zelf-cruciaal-besluit-om-te-starten-op-zachte-banden.html) cites Max Verstappen deliberately choosing to start today's (July 31st, 2022) Hungary Grand Prix on soft tyres, rather than hard ones:

> "Met de harde band zou dat nog veel moeilijker zijn geweest", vertelde de regerend wereldkampioen op de persconferentie. "Ik heb toen meteen gezegd: no way dat wij op hard gaan beginnen."

My translation:

> "It would have been much more difficult with the hard tyres", told the reigning world champion at the press conference. "I immediately said: no way we're starting on hard."

Why was he able to choose on which tyre to start? I thought drivers which made the third qualifying stage (Q3) were required to start on the tyres with which they made their fastest lap in Q2. Max Verstappen had engine issues in Q3 and his engine was replaced, did that give him a way out?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The (Q2 tyre) rule was dropped for 2022: https://www.autosport.com/f1/news/f1-regulations-update-confirms-removal-of-q2-tyre-rule/8313153/

> The FIA has confirmed Formula 1 drivers qualifying inside the top 10 will no longer be required to start the race on their Q2 tyre from the 2022 season.